# Problem: The use of JOptionPane stops my JPanels from switching

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, joptionpane

So the purpose of this code is to use JOptionPane to get a user input, verify it, make sure the input is "Hello World", and if it is, switch from the red JPanel to the blank one with the JLabel Hello World at the top. However, when "Hello World" is typed into the textfield in the JPanel and OK is clicked, the red JPanel is removed but the blank one with the JLabel does not appear. I used the isDisplayable() method to check if the blank JPanel with the JLabel is displayed and the result is true. I am not sure what the issue is or how to solve it. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Main {

    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
    private static JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
    private static JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("Hello World");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        colorPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.add(colorPanel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter");
        if(input.equals("Hello World"))
        {
            frame.remove(colorPanel);
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
            testPanel.add(testLabel);
            frame.add(testPanel);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Best to use a CardLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frame.validate()` should be `frame.revalidate()` and should happen after all components adds/removes"

```
if(input.equals("Hello World"))
{
    frame.remove(colorPanel);
    testPanel.add(testLabel);
    frame.add(testPanel);
    frame.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer to the wrong question. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62505088/418556) for the way that was *designed* for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you've got an accepted answer, but I have to chime in since I feel that while the answer is technically correct, it may not be the best solution.

Note that first of all, your problem has less to do with `.validate()` vs `.revalidate()` and more to do with where you're calling this. It must be called *after* all changes have been done, meaning after all components have been removed *and* added.

Note also that it is usually good to have `repaint()` on your container and calling it *after* calling `revalidate()` especially if you remove components since this will help clear up any potential "dirty" pixels in your GUI.

Now to the meat of my answer: best not to roll your own solution but rather to use the higher level tools that your GUI library offers you, here a CardLayout (tutorial: [CardLayout Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)). Using this tool allows you to easily scroll forward or backward through "card" components, here JPanels using the `.previous(...)` and `.next(...)` methods, or to swap components in a flexible way by calling the `.show(...)` method. The layout will also size the container that uses the layout and holds the "card" components so that all cards are guaranteed to fit.

An example of use of .`next(...)`, `.previous(...)` and `.show(...)` can be seen in the compilable and runnable code below. Also, please have a look at the comments:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwapPanels extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(); // the layout
    private JPanel cardHolderPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout); // the JPanel that holds the cards
    
    // a combo box and model for allowing random-access swapping
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    private JComboBox<String> swapPanelCombo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);

    public SwapPanels() {
        // listener added to combobox to allow swapping of panels
        swapPanelCombo.addActionListener(e -> swapPanel());
        
        JButton previousBtn = new JButton("Previous");
        previousBtn.addActionListener(e -> cardLayout.previous(cardHolderPanel));
        
        JButton nextBtn = new JButton("Next");
        nextBtn.addActionListener(e -> cardLayout.next(cardHolderPanel));
        
        // panel to hold buttons and combo box
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.add(previousBtn);
        controlPanel.add(nextBtn);
        controlPanel.add(swapPanelCombo);
        
        // create and add our "card" JPanels, showing different colors 
        addColorPanel("White", Color.WHITE);
        addColorPanel("Red", Color.RED);
        addColorPanel("Orange", Color.ORANGE);
        addColorPanel("Yellow", Color.YELLOW);
        addColorPanel("Green", Color.GREEN);
        addColorPanel("Blue", Color.BLUE);
        addColorPanel("Cyan", Color.CYAN);
        
        // add components to the main *this* JPanel
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 450));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cardHolderPanel);
        add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private void addColorPanel(String text, Color color) {
        // create color JPanel
        JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
        colorPanel.setBackground(color);

        // label to display color name
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        // make label big
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f));
        
        // place label in the center of the color JPanel
        colorPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        colorPanel.add(label);

        // add text to your jcombo box as well
        comboModel.addElement(text);

        // add color panel to the card-holder JPanel
        cardHolderPanel.add(colorPanel, text);
    }
    
    private void swapPanel() {
        // get combo box's text
        String text = (String) swapPanelCombo.getSelectedItem();
        if (text != null) {
            // use the text to swap jpanels
            cardLayout.show(cardHolderPanel, text);
        }
    }

    // be sure to show our GUI on the Swing event thread
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwapPanels mainPanel = new SwapPanels();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swap Panels");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```